# Como hago para contar la cantidad de palabras de un texto en C?

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

> Ingresar un texto de caracteres utilizando la función `getchar( )`. Indicar la cantidad de caracteres, palabras, y líneas que lo forman. Mostrar lo pedido con carteles aclaratorios. Considerar como separadores de palabras válidos: espacio, tabulador y enter y tener en cuenta que contar palabras no es contar cantidad de separadores. El texto ingresado podrá contener cualquier tipo de caracteres, incluido el enter.

El problema es que cuando ejecuto lo que hice me marca el siguiente error:

> ```
> invalid conversion from `char' to `const char*'
> ```

Quisiera saber como solucionarlo y si esta bien planteado la forma que hice para contar las palabras del texto. Gracias

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int cantpalabras(char *);

int main()
{
    int longcarac,cantp;
    char text;

    printf ("Ingrese el texto \n");
    text=getchar();
    longcarac=strlen(text);
    cantp=cantpalabras(text);
    printf ("La cantidad de palabras es: %d \n", cantp);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int cantpalabras(char *at)
{
    int cont=0;
    int *punt=at;
    while (*punt)
    { if (*punt='\n'||*punt='\t')
      { cont=cont+1;
        punt++; } }

    return cont; }
```

Comment: lo que más mola es que junto a la definición del problema nos pone siempre el número del ejercicio jajajaja. Yo personalmente estoy de risas, no me lo tomo a mal porque intentas crear una solución y no la pides directamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una pequeña crítica, con ánimo constructivo: te recomiendo que leas la documentación de las funciones que usas o que quieres usar:

> size_t strlen(const char *s);
>
> Devuelve la longitud de la cadena apuntada por s, excluyendo el 0 del final de la cadena.

Con esto presente, veamos tu código:

```
char text;
text = getchar();
...
longcarac = strlen( text );
```

Claramente, no puedes usar `strlen( )` en **caracteres individuales**, tan solo en **punteros** a *cadenas*.

Además, si miramos

> int getchar( void );
>
> Lee el siguiente caracter de 'stdin' y lo devuelve como un 'unsigned char' promocionado a 'int'. En caso de error o de FIN DEL FICHERO, devuelve EOF.

Claramente, tu código **no va a funcionar**; tan solo lees **1** caracter, no el texto que te solicitan. Deberías de hacer un bucle, mantener una cadena con el texto, ir sumando los caracteres, ...